# Has anyone installed material-components outside of CocoaPods?

Tags: cocoapods, material-components, material-components-ios

I was wondering if anyone managed to setup [material-components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) on Xcode, outside of using CocoaPods (i.e. Carthage).

It seems to be heavily CP-dependent.

Comment: The [material-components-ios](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) currently supports [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) and [Bazel](https://bazel.build/). Is there a specific request for Carthage or will Bazel work for your needs?

Comment: Ive never used Bazel but i prefer using Carthage..